# Place to place aspects in a Maven projects

Tags: maven, aop, aspectj

i would like to do a check where most of you have been placing your aspects in a Maven project?

I can imagine:

```
src/main/aspect

public aspect SecurityAspect{}
```

Although i have not seen it anywhere mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no src/main/aspect directory in the [standard maven directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). I personally create a separate package for my aspects (within of course src/main/java).

Comment: Would you consider placing it in src/main/aspect just as src/test/java in the case of JUnit?

Comment: On the other hand, the aspectj plugin's default aspectDirectory setting points to src/main/aspect by default, so I guess, it would be more of personal choice for me. =) http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#aspectDirectory